# not able to implement animation on child elements of Fragment class

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-viewpager

one of the fragments contains buttons ,onclick of which I'm generating a dialog which contains a layout,but not able to animate the dialog layout ,my code is

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements AnimationListener {
    ImageButton btn,bbtn;
    Context cxt;

    RelativeLayout fragment;
     PageAdapter pPage ;
        FragmentActivity activity;
        View pFirst;
        Animation animation;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (container == null) {

            return null;
        }
        cxt=getActivity();
        this.activity=getActivity();

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
     vPOp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pfirst, container, false);


        btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Dialog d = new Dialog(cxt);
                        d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                        new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                d.setContentView(R.layout.up);
                d.show();
                initialsePaging();

            }
        });
        bBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Dialog d1 = new Dialog(cxt);

                d1.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                        new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                d1.setContentView(R.layout.pfirst);
                d1.show();

                 vFirst = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pfirst, container, false);
                    ImageButton bBtn = (ImageButton) vFirst.findViewById(R.id.bowl);
                    bBtn.setY(400);
                    bBtn.setX(20);
                    nimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(cxt, R.anim.move_up);
                    bBtn.startAnimation(animation);
                    bBtn.setTranslationY(300);


            }
        });





                return v;
    }



    protected void initialsePaging() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Fragment> fragment = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragment.add(Fragment.instantiate(cxt, FTab1.class.getName()));
        fragment.add(Fragment.instantiate(cxt, FTab2.class.getName()));
        pPageAdapter = new PageAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragment);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)pfirst.findViewById(R.id.VF);
        pager.setAdapter(pPageAdapter);

            }



    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Neither do the animation on click is running nor the another viewpager elements are getting initialized ,what is the best way to do this,new using viewpager ,pl guide

Comment: first problem solved with

Comment: dialog.setContentView( pFirst);
    dialog.show();